# Xcode - convert image URLs in an array to UIImages

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutable Array that has 2 URLS (strings) in them.

```
//An NSMutable Array with 2 Image URLS stored on local folder

ImageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://localhost/images/
image1.jpg", @"http://localhost/images/image2.jpg", nil];
```

I want to convert these two image URLS to UIImages.

```
for(int i = 0; i < [ImageArray count]; i++)
{
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:[ImageArray objectAtIndex:i]]]];

    //After converted, replace the same array with the new UIImage Object
    [ImageArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject: image];
}
```

I think the above should (?) work? But when I assign the images to the imageview, nothing shows up when I run the program.

```
ImageView.image = [ImageArray objectAtIndex: 0];
ImageView2.image = [ImageArray objectAtIndex: 1];
```

Since nothing shows up after the program runs, I suspect something is going on in the for loop, but I'm not sure what.

Can anyone help? I feel like I'm making a silly mistake somewhere.

Thank you.

Comment: first store the image in an image object, using `UIImage imageNamed:`

Comment: Are you sure that your for loop is being run before you assign the images to the ImageViews? It is difficult to see what is going on with these snippets of code that are out of context.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Can you explain? The for loop should assign the URLS to the image object.

Comment: @mttrb Yes, it's being run before the images are being assigned to imageviews.

Comment: Your problem is in creating the Mutable Array. I have posted an answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can try with it. It working fine for me.

// Load image url on a Mutable Array.
NSMutableArray *ImageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg",@"http://www.last-video.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/superbe-image-de-poissons-sous-l-eau.jpg", nil];

//Getting Images from Url
for(int i = 0; i < [ImageArray count]; i++)
{
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                              [NSURL URLWithString:[ImageArray objectAtIndex:i]]]];

    //After converted, replace the same array with the new UIImage Object
    [ImageArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject: image];
}

//Load images on ImageView
int XX=0;
for (int k=0; k<[ImageArray count]; k++)
{
    UIImageView *imgVw=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XX, 0, 200, 300)];
    [imgVw setImage:[ImageArray objectAtIndex:k]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgVw];
    XX=XX+200;
}
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't allocate the array. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Break this statement into smaller statements

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:[ImageArray objectAtIndex:i]]]];
```

There could be multiple points of failure here

1. The NSURL object created is nil (use encoding of the NSString to replace any spaces or even check if the path is correct
2. Make sure the image at this path is correct and that the NSData object created does in fact have data

Comment: This helped a lot with debugging. I wish I could give you the answer but someone else solved it. Thank you SO MUCH for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unsafe to use the only array for storing objects several types.

Firstly, create second array, say `paths` for url paths and `images` for loaded images. I prefer not to keep image objects in array and just set it to image view right after it loaded.

Secondly, your loading operations can take much device resources. For prevent your interface freeze for a long time I advice you to perform it in a separate queue. You can read more about Grand Central Dispatch [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/index.html). It's really useful development tool.

Thirdly, as @newgeapps_dev already said, you need to check your variables created well. Check at least NSURL and NSData for `nil`.

Here's some code snippet for you.

```
- (void)loadImagesFromPaths:(NSArray *)paths
{
  for (NSUInteger index=0;index<paths.count;index++)
  {
    NSString *path = paths[index];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    if (!url) // check url initialized
      continue;
    // load image data asynchronously in a separate queue with a low priority
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
      NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
      if (!data)
        return; // if no data - return from block
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
      if (!image)
        return; // if no image provided by url - do nothing
      if (index==0)
        [self.imageView0 setImage:image];
      else if (index==1)
        [self.imageView1 setImage:image];
      else  //.. etc
    });
  }
}
```